# how to popup successful message after sending the message in controller, using c#, MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, smtp

I am sending email using smpt. I can send the email successfully.I have tested it and received.now my problem is how can I show a success or error message after finish the email send process(up to now only success is also enough) within the controller.I have attached my code here which is inside my controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetEnquiryData(string FirstName, string LastName, string Email, string PhoneNumber, string TravelCalendar, string TravelNights, string TravelMonth, string TNoAdults, string TNoChildren, string SpecialOc, string GettoKnow, string TCUKMember, string Tdate, string Tprice, string byemail, string dealRef, string ConTime)
    {
        var firstName = FirstName;
        var lastName = LastName;
        var email = Email;
        var contactNumber = PhoneNumber;
        var travelCalendar = TravelCalendar;
        var travelNights = TravelNights;
        var travelMonth = TravelMonth;
        var TAdults = TNoAdults;
        var TChildren = TNoChildren;
        var SpecialOcc = SpecialOc;
        var GetToKnow = GettoKnow;
        var TcukMember = TCUKMember;
        var Date = Tdate;
        var Price = Tprice;
        var Mail_Call = byemail;
        var DealRef = dealRef;
        var CTime = ConTime;
        string subject = "";
        string body = "";


        //TCNewDBEntities EnquiryEntities = new TCNewDBEntities();
        //Enquiry enQuiryDetails = new Enquiry();

        //enQuiryDetails.FirstName = firstName;
        //enQuiryDetails.LastName = lastName;
        //enQuiryDetails.EmailAddress = email;


        //EnquiryEntities.Enquiries.Add(enQuiryDetails);
        //EnquiryEntities.SaveChanges();


        var fromAddress = "inone@Ubr.co.uk";
        subject = "Enquiry Form Details";
        body += "<br /><br /><b>" + Mail_Call + "</b>";
        body += "<br /><br />Deal Reference No." + DealRef;
        body += "<br /><br />First Name : " + firstName;
        body += "<br /><br />Last Name : " + lastName;
        body += "<br /><br />Email Address : " + email;
        body += "<br /><br />Contact Number : " + contactNumber;
        body += "<br /><br />Traveling From : " + travelCalendar;
        body += "<br /><br />Nights : " + travelNights;
        body += "<br /><br />Date : " + Date + " " + travelMonth;
        body += "<br /><br />Price : " + Price;
        body += "<br /><br />No. Adults : " + TAdults;
        body += "<br /><br />No. Children : " + TChildren;
        body += "<br /><br />Special Occasion : " + SpecialOc;
        body += "<br /><br />Know About Deals: " + GetToKnow;
        body += "<br /><br />Convenient Time:" + CTime;
        body += "<br /><br />Voucher Code: " + TcukMember;


        MailMessage mailP = new MailMessage();
        mailP.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
        mailP.To.Add(new MailAddress("abcd@gmail.com"));
        mailP.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(email));
        mailP.Subject = "'" + subject + "'";
        mailP.Body = body;
        mailP.IsBodyHtml = true;

        using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
        {
            var credential = new NetworkCredential
            {
                UserName = "smtpubr",
                Password = "12ubr34"
            };

            smtpClient.Credentials = credential;
            smtpClient.Host = "smtpttcorpeo.com";
            smtpClient.Port = 2322;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

            await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailP);
        }

        return Json(new { });
    }
```

hope your help with this.

Comment: Just redirect to any page (in this case to success page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you return object example like This

```
public class ServerResponse
{
public string ErrorMessage {get; set;}
public string SuccessMessage {get; set;}
}
```

And then

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> GetEnquiredData(string FirstName, string LastName, string Email, string PhoneNumber, string TravelCalendar, string TravelNights, string TravelMonth, string TNoAdults, string TNoChildren, string SpecialOc, string GettoKnow, string TCUKMember, string Tdate, string Tprice, string byemail, string dealRef, string ConTime)
 {
        var serverResponse = new ServerResponse();
        try { //Send Email here
        serverResponse.SuccessMessage = "Success!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        serverResponse.ErrorMessage= $"Error! + {ex.Message}";
        }
       return Json(serverResponse, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
 }
```

After it check via ajax what server responsed. And show message! 
Hope it helps

js

```
$.ajax({
url : /YourURL/GetEnquiredData,
data : {your data}
}).success(function(response)
{ if (response.ErrorMessage!=null)
{ 
showError(response.ErrorMessage):
}
else {
showSucess(response.SuccessMessage);
}

});
```